# How can I use 2 Line-In microphones with the same Dragon NaturallySpeaking user profile?

Tags: windows, microphone, dragon-naturally-speaking

How can I use 2 Line-In microphones with the same Dragon NaturallySpeaking user profile?

After configuring the  Dragon NaturallySpeaking user profile for the first Line-In microphone, I don't see any Line-In when trying to add a new dictation source:

[image]

[image]

I use Dragon NaturallySpeaking 12.5 Professional with Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From http://www.knowbrainer.com/forums/forum/messageview.cfm?catid=4&threadid=33158&forumid=1 ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20190508085829/http://www.knowbrainer.com/forums/forum/messageview.cfm?catid=4&threadid=33158&forumid=1)):

> [Stephan Kuepper](http://www.knowbrainer.com/forums/forum/tombstone.cfm?ProfileID=146): Short answer: you can't. In Dragon versions before 13, you can only use one mic type each. From the screenshot, it looks like you've already used up most available sources, so the only way I can think of is to delete the Mic-In source and use that. Or upgrade to DPI / DPG 15.